# problem in saving url in jquery/mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

hey guys im trying to save a url link in a html form  but problem is i cant save urls like this :

> modules.php?name=phpBB3&file=memberlist

but the result after using jquery is this url :

```
modules.php?name=phpBB3
```

i heard i should use json  but no idea how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) should help

```
data: "link="+encodeURIComponent(link)
```

Or pass data as object not string. jQuery will encode values itself:

```
data: {
  link: link
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what does the client send when you invoke POST from jquery? you can use Fiddler to see the http traffic.